# Android RecyclerView Adapter not initialize

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

At first sorry for my poor English.
I am working withe Android RecyclerView. From my Activity send request to server for data and get response from server by calling sendRequestForHistory() Method in onCreate method. After calling sendRequestForHistory() then initialize my data adapter but here my ArrayList is empty. In sendRequestForHistory() method get data from server and add to ArrayList. My code like this.

```
public class HistoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Toolbar toolbar;
private ProgressDialog PD;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private HistoryAdapter historyAdapter;
private Boolean isInternetPresent = false;
private ConnectionDetector cd;
private TextView tvEmptyView;
private ArrayList<ItemHistory> itemHistories;
protected Handler handler;
private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_history);
    dbHelper= new DatabaseHelper(this);
    handler = new Handler();
    itemHistories = new ArrayList<ItemHistory>();

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    toolbar.setTitle(brandName);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    PD = new ProgressDialog(this);
    PD.setMessage("Loading.....");
    PD.setCancelable(false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_history);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    sendRequestForHistory();

    // Here itemHistories is empty.
    historyAdapter = new HistoryAdapter(itemHistories, recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(historyAdapter);
    historyAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  } 

 private void sendRequestForHistory() {
 //send request to server and get response history data 
 // then history dada add to itemHistories ArrayList

 itemHistories.add(new ItemHistory(requestReceiver[i], requestAmount[i],requestCost[i]);

  }
}
```

Comment: can you show adapter code?

Comment: @ Matthew Shearer , Thanks I think adapter class is ok. when I use                   '   historyAdapter = new HistoryAdapter(itemHistories, recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(historyAdapter);
    historyAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); ' in sendRequestForHistory() it works fine.

Comment: does sendRequestForHistory() create a new thread somehow?  If so the setting the adapter would need to wait until this has completed.

Comment: Thanks @MatthewShearer , It is solved. its my mistake. solved it by     ` itemHistories.add(new ItemHistory(requestReceiver[i], requestAmount[i],requestCost[i]);     historyAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you,You are making Internet call thats why when response is receiving then you can add

```
private void sendRequestForHistory() {
    ApiClient.getArticles(page, category_name, type).enqueue(new Callback<List<Article>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Article>> call, Response<List<Article>> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessfull()){
                for(Article article: response.body().getList()){
                    historyAdapter.addItem(article);
                }
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),response.message(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Article>> call, final Throwable t) {
           Toast.makeText(getContext,t.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

This  your Adapter class please add "Adding" function inside your adapter not outer cause it will make your code look more awful and complicated.

```
public class HistoryAdapter{


private ArrayList<Article> articleList;

public HistoryAdapter(......){
   articleList = new ArrayList<>();
   .....
}

.....

.....


public void addItem(Article article){
    articleList.add(article);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```